# Spring autowire does not work in simple class, but works everywhere else

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I'm trying to make a new X entity, which has a relation to my User entity. When someone is posting a new X entity, im making an "XForm", to validate the results, etc. And if everything is valid, in the "execute" method, i'm trying to find the user from the **userRepository** based on the id, from the form.

```
package app.form;

public class XForm {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

private long userId;
//[.. other fields + getters and setters]

public X execute() throws Exception {
    X myX= new X();
    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(getUserId());
    if (!user.isPresent()) {
        throw new Exception("User not found");
    }
    myX.setUser(user.get());
    return myX;

}
```

And the userRepository is  null. I **tried** to annotate it with @Component, @Service etc, but its still null. And as you can see i'm not trying to make a "new" UserRepository either. Auto wiring the repository works fine everywhere else (In the Controllers, and the Authentication handlers, etc).

Here is the controller:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> testNewAction(@RequestBody @Valid XForm form,
                                         BindingResult result) {
    try {
        if (isValid(result)) {
            X myX = form.execute();
            XRepository.save(myX);
            //return success json
        }
        //return form errors json
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //return exception json
    }
}
```

The base application class look like this, i made sure its scanned too (app.form):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"config", "app"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"app.entity"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"config", "app"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Comment: Yes, annotate the XForm owner of the repository as a Component, Bean, or Service.  As written it's not under Spring's control.

Comment: Like i said in the description, i tried to annotate the XForm with "@Service" and "@Component" and it didn't work. And i'm not using new, i'm using autowired.

Comment: Can you show us your package structure? That `@ComponentScan` is not good. And it might be unecessary if you main class is in the base package of all other classes

Comment: From a design POV, I don't think execute() belongs in XForm - traditionally those forms are just transfer objects...

Comment: I'm using command pattern, but tried to keep it simple in the "example error". (Using the same code to reproduce the error). Thanks for the suggestion tho @moilejter

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that XForm is not created as a Spring bean, but just as a plain Java object.  In such cases, you can make the class @Configurable, and Spring will help you instantiate at the time new gets called.  Here's an example of how to do it: https://sichernmic.blogspot.com/2015/04/use-of-configurable-annotation.html

Comment: i annotated the XForm with #Configurable (org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable)
And the Application with #EnableSpringConfigured ( org.springframework.context.annotation.aspectj.EnableSpringConfigured) It's still not working. I think your answer is right tho. Am i missing something critical in the example? (Cannot use @ in the annotations)

Comment: Did you add all the Maven dependencies for it?  Spring Boot will not activate a feature if the right pieces are not in the classpath, I think ...

Comment: i did, but when i added the plugin to the build, then it wouldn't compile. If i don't add it, it's compiling but not working.

Comment: What error do  you get?  Could you post this project somewhere, so we can try tinkering with it, rather than creating a parallel one from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

### Diagnosis

I have faced the exact same thing and its very frustrating problem to solve. You don't understand whats wrong. But I finally figured out what the issue was. It is not that Spring is unable to detect `XForm`, no! Spring will very well create a bean of `XForm` for you. You can check that out using the following code :

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    return args -> {
    System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring:");

    String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    Arrays.sort(beanNames);
    for (String beanName : beanNames) {
      System.out.println(beanName);
    }
  };
}
```

### Problem

The real problem lies with `@RequestBody`. What `@RequestBody` does (with the help of `HttpMessageConverter`) is that it tells the MVC controller to create an instance of `XForm` using the no-arg constructor, and then call setter methods with the values of the incoming HTTP POST request. Now since `@RequestBody` creates object using the no-arg constructor, the dependencies (`UserRepository`, in this case) are never injected and you get a null pointer for your service.

### Kind of Solution

What you can try doing is, try creating another augmented constructor and call it from within the no-arg constructor like so :

```
public XFrom(UserService userService){
    this.userService = userService;
}
```

I am not sure if this will work, but its definitely worth a shot.

Comment: Not as written, since you'd still have to get your hands on the UserService to pass in...

Answer (score 0):

You need all of the following:

1. Annotate `XForm` with `@Component`
2. Annotate `UserRepository` in `XForm` with `@Autowired`
3. In your Java config define the `UserRepository` bean along with the creation logic
4. In your `@ComponentScan` mention the package of `XForm` (ensure the syntax is correct)

An example below:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "com.mycompany.app1",
    "com.mycompany.app2"
})
```

From your description, it seems you did the first 3 points. Only the last one is missing.

Comment: The "app" is my base package, and the XForm is in "app.form", since its just a base package it should be included, isn't it?

Comment: @iron24 How are you launching the app? from a jar or IDE? If it is from a jar, how are you creating the jar? If the jar is being created from IDE, make sure to check the options that creates the jar with the package folder structure

Comment: Using IntellIJ Idea, and just casually pressing the "run" button. Used mvn clean, and package as well.

Comment: @iron24 Please post you configuration for `UserRepository` bean

Comment: @Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> , QuerydslPredicateExecutor<User>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QUser>